# How to plot the predicted chances of something and the actual chances of something among years in KNN in python

Tags: python, plot, knn

I am trying to plot a figure for the predicted chances of flood from the year 2020 to 2040. I got an error regarding the array that contains the predictions as 0: no flood and 1: flood and I got error key 1.

```
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
import sys
from datetime import datetime


clf = neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier()
knn_clf = clf.fit(x_train,y_train)

#Let's predict chances of flood
y_predict = knn_clf.predict(x_test)
print('predicted chances of flood')
print(y_predict)


startDate = 2020
endDate = 2040
          
      
yes_flood_y_predict = []

no_flood_y_predict = []


for i in range(2020,2041):
  for j in range(41):
    if (y_predict[j]==1.0):
        yes_flood_y_predict.append(i)     
    else: 
        no_flood_y_predict.append(i)

       


plt.scatter(range(2020, 2041), yes_flood_y_test, color='blue')
plt.scatter(range(2020, 2041), yes_flood_y_predict, color='red')
plt.title("predicted chances of flood")
plt.show()
```

I want to be able to plot the predicted floods among the years from 2020 to 2040 on the graph.